# ¿Cual es el Script para mover una Base data Ya CReada en SQL server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Buen Dia tardes o noches. Tengo una BATABASE ya creada en manager studio de SQL server 2008 R2, deseo mover la BASEDATA  (archivos de extencion .mdf y .ldf)la pregunta es ¿Existe algun script MOVE que me mueva a una nueva ubicacion fisica de esas extenciones? que esta en el disco duro C ubicacion X la quiero mover al disco duro D:\BATABASE*.mdf y *.ldf

Comment: App web, escritorio o android?

Answer (score 1):

Juan Carlos , justo este tema me toco abordar en un trabajo .

Como sabras SQL permite la ejecución de comandos cmd . Con el comando que anteriormente nombras podes mover una base de datos de una ruta a otra , luego debes indicarle al motor de la base de datos cual es la nueva dirección.

Te adjunto un script que me ha servido para esto al 100%

```
-- Mostramos las rutas actuales de la base de datos.

USE master SELECT name, physical_name FROM sys.master_files

-- Tomamos nota de los datos de la BD que queremos mover, por ejemplo:
--
-- SYSADMIT-DB         C:\test\SYSADMIT-DB.mdf
-- SYSADMIT-DB_log     C:\test\SYSADMIT-DB_log.ldf
--
-- Siendo la primera columna el nombre lógico de la base de datos y
-- la segunda columna la ruta física
--

GO

-- Situamos la base de datos a offline, haciendo el rollback inmediato de 
-- todas las transacciones abiertas.

ALTER DATABASE "SYSADMIT-DB" SET offline WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

GO

-- Procedemos a mover los ficheros, por ejemplo desde CMD con el comando move.
-- Abrimos una ventana de CMD y ejecutamos:
--

md "D:\MSSQLData"
Move "C:\test\SYSADMIT-DB.mdf" "D:\MSSQLData\SYSADMIT-DB_Data.mdf"
Move "C:\test\SYSADMIT-DB_log.ldf" "D:\MSSQLData\SYSADMIT-DB_log.ldf"


-- Modificamos la ruta del MDF de la base de datos.
-- El nombre lógico de la base de datos está obtenido después de la ejecución 
-- del primer comando.

ALTER DATABASE "SYSADMIT-DB" MODIFY FILE ( NAME = "SYSADMIT-DB", FILENAME = "D:\MSSQLData\SYSADMIT-DB_Data.mdf")

GO

-- Modificamos la ruta del LDF de la base de datos.
-- El nombre de la base de datos está obtenido después de la ejecución del primer comando.

ALTER DATABASE "SYSADMIT-DB" MODIFY FILE ( NAME = "SYSADMIT-DB_Log", FILENAME = "D:\MSSQLData\SYSADMIT-DB_Log.ldf")

GO

-- Situamos la base de datos online.

ALTER DATABASE "SYSADMIT-DB" SET online

GO

-- Mostramos las rutas actuales de las base de datos

USE master SELECT name, physical_name FROM sys.master_files
```

Ante cualquier duda , estoy a disposición.

Saludos

Ignacio Loyte